# How to create option to insert time stamp?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, shortcut-keys, nautilus-actions

While editing text documents I need to put time stamps frequently. I thought of automating it in 2 different ways. None of these seem to be working.

1. Using nautilus-actions

I set up a new right-context action which runs the command `date|xclip`

[image]

This right-context doesn't show up when I right click in other applications (such as terminal, or browser). Moreover when it appears, and I click on it, it doesn't do anything.

2. Using keyboard shortcut

I setup a new keyboard shortcut which is supposed to execute `date` command but doesn't.

[image]

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GNOME keyboard shortcuts should work.

Here's why what you tried didn't work: Your keyboard shortcut runs the `date` command, but does nothing with the output (which just gets discarded). You should pipe it to `xclip`, as `date | xclip` to copy it to the X selection (*not* clipboard). [Then you can paste it into your document by middle-clicking.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/pasting-x-selection-not-clipboard-contents-with-keyboard) If you want to be able to use Ctrl-V, instead use `date | xclip -selection c` to copy it to the actual clipboard.

Another alternative is to use [`xdotool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool/) to type the date directly into your document. Assign to your shortcut

```
xdotool type "$(date)"
```

Then, when you press the shortcut key, it will calculate the current date and type the characters it into your document.

For ISO 8601 format, use `xdotool type "$(date --rfc-3339=s)"`.

---

If it doesn't work: Because these are shell commands (as opposed to executables), you might have to pass the command to `bash` when specifying them in your shortcut. Your command would then be:

```
bash -c 'xdotool type "$(date --rfc-3339=s)"'
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. But it's not working. I assigned the shortcut to CTRL+; and I click this particular combination on desktop and then I click CTRL+V (say in gmail) but it doesn't paste. Do I have to restart laptop?

Comment: @user13107: It turns out that by default, `xclip` copies the text not to the clipboard, but to the X selection. To paste it, use middle-click rather than Ctrl-V.

Comment: Using `bash -c` did the trick but there is some kind of delay in typing. When I click the shortcut, complete timestamp is not typed using xdotool. Some initial numbers are eaten up e.g. `1-07 15:14:35+08:00`or `013-01-07 15:14:35+08:00`

Comment: Yes, the {xclip, middle-click} solution works! But it still needs me to click twice. One for keyword shortcut, another for middle-click. I don't know why xdotool seems to give glitches. Thanks, anyways!

Comment: @user13107 I had the same issue. After some trial and error I ended up with the command `bash -c 'date | xclip -selection clipboard && xdotool key 'ctrl+v''` that works perfectly.

Comment: @user13107 - this is because you don't use `xdotool --clearmodifiers` - some keys are typed with the Ctrl (e.g. - space, it gets swallowed). Some characters won't be typed (e.g. `:` - which is shifted), but I'm using a following command: `xdotool type --clearmodifiers $(date "+%Y-%m-%d,%H-%I")` which works for me.

Comment: putting this on keyboard shortcut only generates $(date "+%Y-%m-%d,%H-%I") and not the actual date value

Answer (score 6):

I've been successfully using this as a custom keyboard shortcut assigned to `Ctrl+Shift+D`:

```
bash -c 'sleep 0.3 && xdotool type "$(date -u +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%SZ)"'
```

I found adding a slight delay solved the issues with missing initial characters, and doesn't pollute my clipboard.

Note that I'm using a slightly customized version of RFC 3339/ISO 8601 format: I often use this in contexts where I want to avoid the space in `date`'s RFC 3339 output, but I find the `T` that separates the date from the time in ISO 8601 timestamps rather unintuitive and difficult to read, so I find an underscore works well.

Answer (score 3):

```bash
bash -c 'xdotool keyup super && xdotool type "$(date +%Y.%m.%d)"'
```

I use `Super+Q` as my shortcut, and I need to clear the `super` modifier before sending the `date`. I tried `--clearmodifiers` but that would cause the `unity dash` to pop up after the shortcut is run [1]

[1] The reason `unity dash` would pop up afterward is before the `super` is restored if `--clearmodifiers` is used
Quote from `man xdotool`

```
CLEARMODIFIERS
       Any command taking the --clearmodifiers flag will attempt to clear any
       active input modifiers during the command and restore them afterwards.
```